# Deleting items using XSLT

Tags: xml, xpath, transform

So I've been scouring the internet for a few days now and cant seem to find anything specific to my issue. I need to delete an item using XSLT transform, when I receive a match. I have a XPath expression that compares a database extract and am API extract and identifies the matches between the two. I'm trying to use the matches and delete them from the overall API extract. My apologies if I missed any needed information, i'm still fairly new to XSLT.

Current XML format:

```
<names>
  <name>one</name>
  <name>two</name>
  <name>three</name>
  <name>four</name>
</names>
```

Desired XML output:

```
<names>
  <name>one</name>
  <name>two</name>
  <name>four</name>
</names>
```

In this case, lets say I received a match of 'three' the XSLT transform would delete 'three' from the XML.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid the hassle of writing an XSL program, assuming `xmlstarlet` is installed on your system and your XML file is called `names.xml`, you could just issue:

```
xmlstarlet edit --delete '//name[text() = "three"]' names.xml
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this without xmlstarlet? The software I am using does not allow any added utilities. Thanks

Comment: Please accept my solution clicking on the ✓ symbol and vote it up by clicking on ▲.

Comment: @Maharshee: you can do it with an XSL stylesheet. Are you interested in that solution?

Comment: Thank you for the solution! When I try accepting the solution I get "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score." Really appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

If `xmlstarlet` is not available, you can use next XSL stylesheet:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <!-- identity transformation -->
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="name[text() = 'three']"/>
    <!-- do nothing, i.e. delete from output -->

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Or <xsl:apply-templates select="name[text() != 'three']"/>. Then there's no need for the "do nothing" template.

Comment: @Dabbler: you are right, but this script was generated from a template from my own software kitchen. Thank you for this improvement.